# COMBINING DATA FROM 3 tables into one single file

Tags: ssis

I have 3 different tables with data. The total length of all the fields in each table is same.

Table 1 - field 1 char(20),field 2 char(10) like that m fields. total bytes from all fields is 700.

Table 2 - field 1 char(20),field 2 char(5) like than n fields. total bytes from
all fields is 700.
Table 3 - field 1 char(20),field 2 char(2) like than m fields. total bytes from
all fields is 700.

Table 1 has 14 rows
Table 2 has  6 rows
Table 3 has  4 rows

is there anyway in SQLSERVER 2016 or SSIS to combine all the 3 table data 
output should be 24 rows.

Comment: Yes, it's easy.   What have you tried?

Comment: tried UNION ALL transformation in SSIS but when during mapping I could not combine single table 2 fields are more than table 1.

Comment: Did you try `UNION ALL` in `SQL-SERVER`? Sometimes `SSIS` complains when the length of fields don't match (e.g. field 2 in your case).

Comment: yes, I tried union all in SQL Server,still it is not getting the needed result.getting error

Comment: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the SELECT queries so that each query returns the same number of columns with the same datatypes.   This means that for tables that have fewer columns, you will need to add dummy columns like

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, NULL AS Col3, etc...
```

To make sure they are the same datatype, go into the Advanced Editor of the Source Component and set the SSIS datatypes of the output columns, so they are the same for each table.

Then you will be able to combine the tables with the UNION ALL transformation with no problem.